# Create a From Statement or Set Statement for an Update using a declare variable

Tags: sql-server

### I have an audit table that contains the table that had an action against it (update, insert, delete).  In addition to the Tablename that the audit pertains to it includes a recordid that the action specifically pertains to.  I need to retrieve data from another column (accountnumber) which is in this audited table (A01c) but not the audit table.

```
SELECT Distinct 
SEC03.AccessorDescription,
ActionDateTime,
Action,
Count(distinct X30.RecordId) NbrofEntries,
X30.TableId,
TableName,
X30.TableRecordId,
X30.RecordId,
'' Accountnumber  -- *I was unable to determine how to populate this which is when I moved to Dynamic SQL*

FROM  MYDatabase..X30_AuditInformation X30 WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN MYDatabase..X29_AccessorSessions X29 WITH (NOLOCK) on Sessionrecordid = X29.recordid
    INNER JOIN  MYDatabase.[dbo].[SEC03_Accessors] S_SEC03 WITH (NOLOCK) on X29.Sourceid = S_SEC03.SourceID
    INNER JOIN  MYDatabase..SEC03_Accessors SEC03 WITH (NOLOCK) on SEC03.AccessorId = S_SEC03.AccessorId
    INNER JOIN  MYDatabase..SEC06_Roles SEC06 WITH (NOLOCK) on SEC06.RoleID = SEC03.RoleID
    INNER JOIN  MYDatabase..X44_SETables X44 WITH (NOLOCK) on X30.TableId = X44.TableId

WHERE CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) between '08/01/2018' and '08/31/2018'
    AND X29.DatabaseId = 'PROD'
    And SEC06.Description in ('Customer Care Team', 'Operations')
    AND X30.Tableid in ('A01_', 'A01a','A01c', 'A01d', 'A04_','A05_', 'A05a','A05b', 'A05c', 'A05d', 'A07_', 'T01a','T02_','T04_' )
    and X30.RecordId in ('5742402','5743362','5743327','5743399','5743160','5743583','5749828','5749853','5749854','5749912')
GROUP BY SEC03.AccessorDescription,ActionDateTime,X30.Tableid, TableName,TableRecordId,Action,X30.RecordId,ActionDateTime
ORDER BY X30.RecordId
```

For discussion purposes the table names in the attach image are under noted under the column header "FYI".

[Tables associated to difficulty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLrBf.jpg)

---

### When I was unable to determine how to use the TableName from X44 to query the appropriate tables for Accountnumber I thought I would try using Dynamic SQL and was still unsuccessful.

**DataEntyAudit Described**:  Name, ActionDate, Action, TableID, TableName, TableRecordId, Accountnumber

```
Select * from DataEntryAudit where tablerecordid = 14699176 and TableId = 'AcctCodes' 

Declare @Tablename VARCHAR(100)
SET @Tablename = (Select TOP 1 Tablename from MyDatabase..DataEntryAudit)

DECLARE @TableRecordId VARCHAR (25)
SET @TableRecordID = (Select TOP 1 tablerecordid from MyDatabase..DataEntryAudit)

Declare @SQL As Varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'Select accountnumber from '+ @tablename +' ' + 'where'+ ' ' + 'Recordid = ' + '''' + @TableRecordId + ''''
SELECT @SQL

--SELECT @Tablename
--SELECT @TableRecordID

Begin Tran
Update DataEntryAudit
SET Accountnumber =  '('+ @SQL +')'

Select * from DataEntryAudit where tablerecordid = 14699176
```

When I execute this, the Accountnumber is being set to (Select accountnumber from Codes where incrementID = '14699176')  I need the result to be the actual accountnumber from the Tablename that is returned from the Query

[Dynamic SQL Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0TV8.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It seems like something is amiss here. Once you have to resort to dynamic sql like this it is clear indication some changes would help. The real problem is we don't have enough detail to help. But [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is an excellent idea to see what you should post so we can help.

Comment: Afraid I agree with the comment above. Please don't use images of tables/data, just use copy/paste of some data from your tables (with column names) and don't forget to include the table names with each. When preparing this don't try to solve for every problem you may have, simplify down to a single problem. (i.e. keep the number of tables to a practical minimum). Change any names or anything considered private.